# deploying nodejs express 4 application in visual studio to a local folder and run it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently developing a NodeJS project where I need to run it locally on a client environment
The project is as follows
[image]

my question is: is there a way to copy the deployed project to the client server and run it without even installing nodejs or npm on the client server?

also note I can't deploy it to heroku or azure or other services for security purposes as the client may not have access to those services so I only need to deploy it locally

thank you

Comment: "ithout even installing nodejs or npm on the client server" you can bundle it and create a single executable out of it.

Comment: is there a clear example on how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

No, You will need to have NodeJS installed on the server. You can try to create e docker image that uses [NodeJS](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) for easier deployments.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can bundle Node.js apps into "native" binaries.